# shiny for Python using add_layer for Popus from ipyleaflet

Tags: python, html, ipyleaflet, py-shiny

I want to use `m.add_layer` for `Popus` from [ipyleaflet](/questions/tagged/ipyleaflet) in [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) for [python](/questions/tagged/python) ([as given here](https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/popup.html)). However, it is not working as expected. My minimum working example is given below:

```
from shiny import App, render, ui
from shinywidgets import output_widget, reactive_read, register_widget
from ipywidgets import HTML
from ipyleaflet import Map, Marker, Popup

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    output_widget("m")
    )


def server(input, output, session):
    center = (52.204793, 360.121558)
    m = Map(center=center, zoom=9, close_popup_on_click=False)
    message1 = HTML()
    message1.value = "Try clicking the marker!"

# Popup with a given location on the map:
    popup = Popup(
    location=center,
    child=message1,
    close_button=False,
    auto_close=False,
    close_on_escape_key=False
    )
    
    m.add_layer(popup) # This line is not working
    register_widget("m", m)

app = App(app_ui, server)
```

Wondering what basic am I missing here?

Comment: Same problem when using ` @output @render_widget` inside `server` as [in the shinywidgets github examples](https://github.com/rstudio/py-shinywidgets). `Map`and `Marker`work fine. There is [also an open issue about Popup](https://github.com/rstudio/py-shinywidgets/issues/75).

Comment: Which issues are you having?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of an issue in [`ipywidgets`](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/issues/1081). If you install a version of `ipywidgets` < 8 it will work. For example: `pip install ipywidgets==7.6.5` made it work for me.

Answer (score -1):

It looks that the `m.add_layer(popup)` line is not working because you are trying to use the ipyleaflet `Map` object as a Shiny widget, but Shiny does not recognize it. Instead, you can use the `output_widget` function from `shinywidgets` to create a Shiny widget from the ipyleaflet `Map` object, and then add the popup to the map using the `add_layer` method;

```
from shiny import App, render, ui
from shinywidgets import output_widget, reactive_read, register_widget
from ipywidgets import HTML
from ipyleaflet import Map, Marker, Popup

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    output_widget("m")
)


def server(input, output, session):
    center = (52.204793, 360.121558)
    m = Map(center=center, zoom=9, close_popup_on_click=False)
    message1 = HTML()
    message1.value = "Try clicking the marker!"

    # Popup with a given location on the map:
    popup = Popup(
        location=center,
        child=message1,
        close_button=False,
        auto_close=False,
        close_on_escape_key=False
    )

    m.add_layer(popup)

    output.m = output_widget("m", width="100%", height="500px")
    register_widget("m", m)

app = App(app_ui, server)
```